# Why my widget doesn't get installed?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget, installation

I want to install my widget to my home page after i drag and drop it, but when i do it, it says app can't get installed here is my code:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                    int[] appWidgetIds) {

            Intent receiver = new Intent(context, WidgetReceiver.class);
            receiver.setAction("COM_FLASHLIGHT");
            receiver.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

    }
}
```

And my provider info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/more"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:configure="com.flashlight.standroid.WidgetProvider" 
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:label="Monitor Widget">
</appwidget-provider>
```

My Manifest:

```
<receiver 
            android:name=".WidgetProvider" 
            android:icon="@drawable/more" 
            android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.example.flash.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
         </intent-filter>

         <meta-data 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                        android:resource="@xml/provider_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver 
            android:name="WidgetReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.flashlight"></action>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Here i have gathered almost all the parts of code that i use to run/install.. my widget.Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the exact error message?

Comment: "it says" -- what is "it"? If "it" is not LogCat, what warnings or errors are showing up in LogCat?

Comment: on my phone, it appears on widgets, but the moment i try to drag and drop it on my home screen my phone says"app is not installed"

Comment: Please post your manifest, particularly the portion where `com.flashlight.standroid.WidgetProvider` is defined. That would be a rather odd name for an `Activity`.

Comment: Please check out my recent edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `android:configure` from your app widget metadata, or have it point to an **activity** to be used for configuring the app widget.

You can read more about configuration activities in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring).

Comment: I will avoid thanks as i have to do so.. that solved my answer.In addition will go furthermore and ask why when gets installed nothing happens?

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere: I do not know what you are referring to, sorry. Perhaps you may wish to start with a known working app widget project. Here are some from my book: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/PairOfDice https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/Resize https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/TwoOrThreeDice

Answer (score 0):

change

```
android:configure="com.flashlight.standroid.FlashlightWidgetProvider"
```

with

```
android:configure="com.flashlight.standroid.WidgetProvider"
```

And make sure the Activity name is exactly wrote down on the android manifest.